# Circuitikz with comma (,) as decimal mark

Tags: circuitikz

Is there a simple and accurate possibility to use comma as decimal mark in a label of circuitikz (with or without the siunitx option)?

[image: comma as decimal mark in circuitikz]

I mean simpler then use this: `l=${0,\!2}\,\mathrm{A}$` (The circuit above was drawn using this option.)

I tried three possibilities, but all of them worked just with point. Two possibilities can be seen in this example, and it gives an error message, if a change point to comma:

```
\begin{circuitikz} \draw
(0,0) -- (0,2)
    to[ammeter, l_=$0.2\,A$] (4,2)
    to[generic] (4,0)
    to[battery1] (0,0)
(0.5,0) -- (0.5,-1)
      to[voltmeter,l_=1.5<\volt>] (3.5,-1) -- (3.5,0)
;
\end{circuitikz}
```

When I used `l_=$\SI{0,2}{\ampere}$`, the comma was translated to point.

Comment: Could you please make your code into a complete document? It should either compile or it should give the error you're asking about when we try to compile it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your second example, `siunitx` is used, so you can add `\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}` to the preamble.

```
\documentclass[border=4mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz} \draw
(0,0) -- (0,2)
    to[ammeter, l_=0.2<\ampere>] (4,2)
    to[generic] (4,0)
    to[battery1] (0,0)
(0.5,0) -- (0.5,-1)
      to[voltmeter,l_=1.5<\volt>] (3.5,-1) -- (3.5,0)
;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```